# docker: invalid reference format in Mac OS X

Tags: docker, jenkins

I ran the docker run command to run the jenkins image.

But this is the command that was executed in the past, but now an error occurs.

**command**

```
docker run -u root —rm -p 8080:8080 —name jenkins \ -v Users/human/jenkins:/var/jenkins_home \
-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \ jenkins
```

**error**

```
docker: invalid reference format.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

My environment is Mac OS X. What's wrong with me?

Answer (score 1):

It could be the path "Users/human/jenkins" is invalid. If you are using $PWD following the example on Jenkins site, be very careful about possible space character in the "current" path.  That would mess up the command and throw out that error message you posted.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have a parsing issue for the command above, I have changed this `—` to `--`.. this should work:

```
docker run -u root --rm -p 8080:8080 --name jenkins -v Users/human/jenkins:/var/jenkins_home -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock jenkins
```

Or like this:

```
docker run -u root --rm -p 8080:8080 --name jenkins \
-v Users/human/jenkins:/var/jenkins_home \
-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
jenkins
```